# Big notation of sigma 4i (from i = 1 to n)

Tags: asymptotics

Why is the big O of this function O(n^2)?

Isn't this just a sum of constant terms? Shouldn't the function be O(1)?

Comment: Note that questions should be readable without the title, and you can use LaTeX mathematics here. Hint: Gaussian sum. Also, there no such thing as "*the* big O" of a functions; every function is in infinitely many "big Os".

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n 4$ is also the sum of constant terms, but that sum is obviously  $4n$ which is certainly not $O(1)$. The problem you have is that the sum depends on $n$ so can't possibly be constant.